# how to get elements after a string digit?

Tags: python, list, text

I have crazy list. I want to grab items after numbers (they are string). But there are many empty elements in my list that I couldn't remove them.

```
G=['0\n113', 'T\neacher t\nraining \nwithout subject \nspecialisation', ' ', 'Adult literacy and numeracy teacher \ntraining', ' ', 'Class teacher training', ' ', 'Elementary teacher education', ' ', 'Indigenous teacher training', ' ', 'Lower \nsecondary teaching', ' ', 'Primary teaching', ' ', 'Special education teaching', '0\n114', 'T\neacher t\nraining with subject \nspeciali\ns\nation']
```

first I tried to remove empty element as below:

```
remove =  filter(None, G) 
print(list(remove))
```

then I wanted to get the index of digits by following code:

```
integers = [i for i,x in enumerate(G) if  (x.isdigit() 
                                         or x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```

But it didn't remove the empty items. so the second code gives error. any idea to do that?

Comment: There are no empty elements in the list you show. `' '` is not empty, it has a single space in it.

Comment: Anyway, you can use `if len(x) > 0 and (x.isdigit() or (x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit()))`

Comment: ok I thought it counts as empty element. but this doesn't work as well `G.remove(' ')`

Comment: `remove()` only removes the first matching element, so you would need to repeat that until they're all gone. A list comprehension is better for.

Comment: But strings with a space shouldn't cause a problem with your code. It only fails for zero-length strings, because `x[0]` gets an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the string is not empty before testing `x[0]`.

```
integers = [i for i,x in enumerate(G) if x.isdigit() 
                                         or (len(x) > 0 and x[0] == '-' and x[1:].isdigit())]
```